# Django Delete Confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an icon of a trash can for a delete button on a Django site.

It's just an anchor tag with an i tag inside that has its href set to a delete view passing the id of the model element.

It works perfectly fine, but I want to create a dialog popup that asks for confirmation before deleting it.

I have seen a few ways to do this but they all require it to be input instead of an anchor.

I also need to make this work on touch devices as well.

How can I change it to an input element and keep the icon as the button rather than showing a submit button.  And how can I get the dialog to popup and when Yes is clicked, pass the correct url and id to the submit?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a confirm prompt:

```
<a ... onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
```

But you should not do inline javascript so try to add a class and abstract it away. Here it is with jquery:

```
<a class="confirm-delete" ...>Delete</a>
$(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', function(){
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
})
```

Comment: Where would I pass the url and the id

Comment: You said it is working now so you would just leave that as is and add the onclick event. I imagine it was in the `href="/object/24/delete"`. I put `...` for the other attributes for brevity.

Comment: Thank you for adding the jquery version as well, definitely helps to see inline and the jquery versions together!

Comment: Took a while to realize the delete view shouldn't test for method=='POST', 'cause it's a GET

Answer (score 8):

Let this be your anchor tag:

```
<a class="icon-trash" id="delete-object" data-object-id="{{ object.id }}">Delete</a>
```

Note that we have `object.id` with an attribute. We are going to need that in javascript part.

And you can write something like this at bottom of the page right before `body` tag closed:

**UPDATE WITH SNIPPET**

Here you can try the demo. it should work when you put the code right before `body` tag closed:

```js
var elm = document.getElementById('delete-object');
var objectID = elm.getAttribute('data-object-id');
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
elm.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var ask = confirm('r u sure?');
  if (ask && objectID) {
    var r = "Page will be redirected to </object/delete/" + objectID + "/>";
    resultDiv.textContent = r;
  } else {
    resultDiv.textContent = "User cancelled the dialog box...";
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.delete-link {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
}
#result {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="delete-link" id="delete-object" data-object-id="3">Delete</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this attribute on your a / button tag will do the Job:
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"